# expresión no elevada con Math.pow

Tags: java, array

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este código corresponde al enunciado anterior.

```
package Ejercicios_trabajo_final;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math;
public class Ejer_19 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int i=0, l=0, n, x=0;
        
        int a[] = new int[3];
        int b[] = new int[3];
        int c[] = new int[3+1];
     
        while(i <= 3-1){
            System.out.print("A["+(i+1)+"]: ");
            a[i]= entrada.nextInt();
            System.out.print("B["+(i+1)+"]: ");
            b[i]= entrada.nextInt();

            c[i] = (int) Math.pow(2,a[i] - b[i]);
            i++;
        }    
            while(l < 3){
               x = x + c[l];
               l++;
            }
        System.out.println("La diferencia de los vectores (A y B) a la 2 es: "+x);
    }
}
```

lo que he hecho hasta el momento, el problema es que no me eleva las expresión con el **Math.pow**, y no se que hacer, gracias de antemano a todos los que me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Saludos. Revisa el orden de los parámetros de  `Math.pow` ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html ); también te sugiero uses `double` (por el tipo de dato que devuelve `pow`) por  lo menos para `x`..

Comment: Muchas gracias, no sabes cuánto me ayudaste.

Comment: No veo la necesidad explícita de usar `Math.pow`, sobre todo por el hecho del cambio en el tipo de variable (*double*) cuando tus arreglos son de tipo `int`. En cuanto pueda te preparo una respuesta. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Como dije en mi [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/369244/expresi%c3%b3n-no-elevada-con-math-pow#comment662567_369244), no veo la necesidad de usar [`Math.pow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,%20double)) para resolver el problema.

Uno de los motivos es el uso innecesario de una variable de tipo `double` cuando tus `array's` son de tipo `integer`.

El otro motivo, es que el binomio presentado como problema es de tabla. Por lo tanto puedes escribir su fórmula sin problemas.

Se pide calcular el cuadrado de la diferencia para cada elemento *i* de los arreglos `A` y `B`:

```
(A[i] - B[i])^2
```

La fórmula matemática del desarrollo de dicho binomio es:

```
A[i]^2 - (2* A[i] * B[i]) + B[i]^2
```

Y podemos calcular

```
A[i]^2 = A[i] * A[i]
```

Con esto podemos escribir el algoritmo que recorre los arreglos (ambos de la misma dimensión) y calcula la suma acumulada de los binomios.

Por ejemplo:

```java
public class calcSumBinomio {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Tomemos 2 arreglos hardcodeados
    int[] a = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    int[] b = {9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};
    int suma = 0;

    // recorremos los 2 arreglos y calculamos los binomios
    // en cada iteración vamos sumando el resultado al acumulado
    for(int i = 0, len = a.length; i < len; i++) {
      suma += (a[i] * a[i]) - (2 * a[i] * b[i]) + (b[i] * b[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(suma); // 330
  }
}
```

De esta forma obtienes el resultado sin la necesidad de usar `Math.pow()` ni cambiar el tipo de las variables.